# Why does R turn a numeric 1000 into a 999 integer?

Tags: r

I was doing some simulations in R and I noticed I was missing exactly one simulation, after looking into my code I discovered this strange R behaviour:

```
N <- 10000
prop <- 0.9
M <- N * (1 - prop)
print(M)
[1] 1000
print(as.integer(M))
[1] 999
```

Comment: Looks like floating point issue.

Comment: ..and `as.integer()` rounds _toward zero_.

Comment: My confusion had to do more with the rounding than with the non-equality NPE's answer clarified that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `0.9` cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating-point value:

```
> sprintf('%.20f', 0.9)
[1] "0.90000000000000002220"
```

All the calculations that follow give inexact results:

```
> sprintf('%.20f', 10000 * (1 - 0.9))
[1] "999.99999999999977262632"
```